# How to grab specific details of device from result file using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu

#### I have more than 100 Apple Devices in my office. I want the details of particular device I want

##### I used `PyAtv` a python module to scan the devices which are on my network.

So I created a script which gives me the result like this when called.

```
rexter@rexter-pc:~$ python3 scan.py

Scan Results
========================================
       Name: Himanshu Gupta’s Mac mini (intel)
   Model/SW: Macmini8,1, Unknown OS
    Address: 192.168.3.243
        MAC: F0:18:98:EF:D2:E6
 Deep Sleep: False
Identifiers:
 - F0:18:98:EF:D2:E6
 - F01898EFD2E6
Services:
 - Protocol: AirPlay, Port: 7000, Credentials: None, Requires Password: False, Password: None, Pairing: Mandatory
 - Protocol: RAOP, Port: 7000, Credentials: None, Requires Password: False, Password: None, Pairing: Mandatory

       Name: Home Cinema
   Model/SW: Apple TV 4K, tvOS 14.4 build 18K802
    Address: 192.168.3.19
        MAC: C8:D0:83:B0:70:C7
 Deep Sleep: False
Identifiers:
 - C8:D0:83:B0:70:C7
 - 257B0C06-0227-4E42-AEEA-3C2C42B3E829
 - C8D083B070C7
Services:
 - Protocol: AirPlay, Port: 7000, Credentials: None, Requires Password: False, Password: None, Pairing: Mandatory
 - Protocol: Companion, Port: 49152, Credentials: None, Requires Password: False, Password: None, Pairing: Mandatory
 - Protocol: MRP, Port: 49153, Credentials: None, Requires Password: False, Password: None, Pairing: Optional
 - Protocol: RAOP, Port: 7000, Credentials: None, Requires Password: False, Password: None, Pairing: Mandatory

       Name: Pluto - GROUND FLOOR
   Model/SW: ShairportSync, Unknown OS
    Address: 172.17.100.55
        MAC: None
 Deep Sleep: False
Identifiers:
 - E4BB83B4A641
Services:
 - Protocol: RAOP, Port: 8901, Credentials: None, Requires Password: False, Password: None, Pairing: NotNeeded

       Name: 2424
   Model/SW: Apple TV 4K, tvOS 15.0
    Address: 172.17.88.11
        MAC: DC:56:E7:59:79:46
 Deep Sleep: False
Identifiers:
 - DC:56:E7:59:79:46
 - DC56E7597946
Services:
 - Protocol: Companion, Port: 49152, Credentials: None, Requires Password: False, Password: None, Pairing: Mandatory
 - Protocol: AirPlay, Port: 7000, Credentials: None, Requires Password: False, Password: None, Pairing: Mandatory
 - Protocol: RAOP, Port: 7000, Credentials: None, Requires Password: False, Password: None, Pairing: Mandatory
```

But I want to get the results of specific device

```
EXAMPLE >>> python3 scan.py 2424

       Name: 2424
   Model/SW: Apple TV 4K, tvOS 15.0
    Address: 172.17.88.11
        MAC: DC:56:E7:59:79:46
 Deep Sleep: False
Identifiers:
 - DC:56:E7:59:79:46
 - DC56E7597946
Services:
 - Protocol: Companion, Port: 49152, Credentials: None, Requires Password: False, Password: None, Pairing: Mandatory
 - Protocol: AirPlay, Port: 7000, Credentials: None, Requires Password: False, Password: None, Pairing: Mandatory
 - Protocol: RAOP, Port: 7000, Credentials: None, Requires Password: False, Password: None, Pairing: Mandatory
```

#### I tried a lot but the challenge I face is Multiple `Services` and `Identifiers` in the results

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I didn't fully understand the problem - one device have many services (different services with different ports) and can the identifiers are also talking about the same device (remove the : from mac address and you will get the second identifier).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the [`scan`](https://github.com/postlund/pyatv/blob/ccc5a947865da904555af78aa793374caeae503f/pyatv/__init__.py#L30-L87) function.

The `scan` function returns a `List[interface.BaseConfig]`.

The [`BaseConfig`](https://github.com/postlund/pyatv/blob/ccc5a947865da904555af78aa793374caeae503f/pyatv/interface.py#L1026-L1153) contains the property `name`.

So, you can try:

```
name = '2424'

devices = scan(...)

for device in device:
    if device.name == name:
        my_device = device
```

Comment: I tired The same but didnt help :(

Comment: Update your post with the code of `scan.py`

Answer (score 0):

You either pass one or more identifiers (preferably all of them) to scan:

```py
# Single identifier
confs = await pyatv.scan(loop, identifier="id")

# Multiple identifiers
confs = await pyatv.scan(loop, identifier={"id1", "id2", "id3"})
```

It's the same identifiers you see when running `atvremote scan`.

Alternatively you can pass the IP address via hosts (does not work if the device is on another network though).

```py
confs = await pyatv.scan(loop, hosts=["10.0.0.6"])
```

It's all described in the documentation here as well:

https://pyatv.dev/development/scan_pair_and_connect/#scan

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).